# Python - Trying to find zipcode within digits of PI (range of 100,000)

Tags: python, arrays, size, limit, pi

User enters a zipcode, then the program searches the array for the sequence of digits. The earlier digits are being found, but higher digits (50k or so elements in) are not being found within the array, but they should be there.

```
def make_pi():
    q, r, t, k, m, x = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
    for j in range(100000):
        if 4 * q + r - t < m * t:
            yield m
            q, r, t, k, m, x = 10*q, 10*(r-m*t), t, k, (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m, x
        else:
            q, r, t, k, m, x = q*k, (2*q+r)*x, t*x, k+1, (q*(7*k+2)+r*x)//(t*x), x+2


my_array = []

for i in make_pi():
    my_array.append(str(i))

num = input("Enter 5 digit ZIP Code: ")

while (1):
    try:
        val = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Entered value is not an integer")
        num = input("Enter 5 digit ZIP code: ")
        continue

    if (len(num)!=5):
        print("ZIP code must be 5 digits!")
        num = input("Enter 5 digit ZIP Code: ")
    else:
        break

flag = 0

for i in range(len(my_array) - 5):

    if (int(my_array[i]) == int(num[0])):

        if (int(my_array[i + 1]) == int(num[1])):

            if (int(my_array[i+2]) == int(num[2])):

              if(int(my_array[i + 3]) == int(num[3])):

                if (int(my_array[i+4]) == int(num[4])):
                    print("ZIP match found at digit #", i + 1)
                    flag = 1

if (flag == 0):
    print("ZIp match not found")
```

Comment: can you provide an example and for what input it's working and not working

Comment: Your array doesn't yield a value for every iteration of the  loop. When I run this, `my_array` is only 23126 items long so it's not clear what you mean by `50k or so elements`